# Dummy variables Zero inflated Ordered probit mods

Tags: ordinal-data, zero-inflation

I am relatively new to zero-inflated ordered probit models, and I've observed a pattern in the analysis of discrete data. In the research papers I've come across, many discrete variables are grouped into a binary format. For instance, variables are encoded as '1' to denote high salary and '0' otherwise, or as '1' to signify student status and '0' otherwise. I'm curious about the rationale behind this type of grouping and whether there's a specific reason for its widespread use. Additionally, I'm interested in finding resources or references where I can further explore and understand this approach to grouping discrete data